# How to fix git error: RPC failed; HTTP 520 curl 22?

Tags: git

I haven't pushed anything into my repo for a month. Actually, I've added only 2 new files into my project and only did some code refactoring, so the size hasn't drastically changed. I wanted to push them changes into my remote repository on Gitlab.

I used to do it like this:

```
git checkout features
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push -u origin features
```

and it worked a month ago.
Today, it hasn't worked, though.

```
Enumerating objects: 6913, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6913/6913), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4191/4191), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6904/6904), 2.88 GiB | 32.87 MiB/s, done.
Total 6904 (delta 2828), reused 5470 (delta 2495), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; HTTP 520 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 520
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I've searched the internet to find an answer but almost every error people have is `500` not `520`

I've changed HTTP postbuffer size - `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

I've changed HTTP version to 1.1 (even though a month ago I already changed it to 1.1, but I tried it again today) - `git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1`

I've changed HTTP version to 2 - `git config --global http.version HTTP/2`

I've updated git

still the same error

How can I fix it?

Comment: 520 is simply "unknown error": something went wrong and some server somewhere doesn't know *what* went wrong and is just telling you "something is wrong". That makes it really hard to fix! It's as if you shout to your neighbor to have them shout to their neighbor, etc., in order to send a message across the country. All you get back is "something failed" but you don't know if it's that the guy at the other end is dead, or there's a squirrel blocking someone's ears in the middle.

Comment: Your best bet in this case is to call whoever administers the server and have them check *their* logs or watch *their* system as you do your operation.

Comment: How big is what you're trying to upload? Did you try to upload the content in a set of batches instead of a single one?